# How do I Implement SQLite.swift Value Protocol

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

How do I make my classes comply with the Value Protocol for SQLite.swift so I can add them directly to my database.  I have made all of them "Codable" but they need to conform to the Value protocol.

[Attempt to conform to Value protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFFhy.png)

These are the stubs that SQLite.swift wants me to implement but I have not found any documentation that would help me to figure out how to implement them other than saying that coadable types can be used.

[My attempt to add codable class to SQLite.Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKKBT.png)

I would like to get a pointer to some documentation on how to implement the stubs for the Value protocol so that I can make my SQLite.swift database cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here for some example implementations:

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Sources/SQLite/Foundation.swift